# How to fill the gap of a div without using media query?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap cards to build this layout on desktop:

[image]

So far so good, at this width everything is ok as well:

[image]

But from this width to desktop width the container is not filled:

[image]

The HTML to build the card with the images is:

```
<div class="card h-60">
                    <div>
                            <div class="row box">
                                    <div class="box-content formal">
                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                    <img class="imageban" src="img/crm.png" />
                                                    <span><b>CRM</b></span>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="box-right">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/img1.jpg"/>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div>
                        <div class="row box">
                                <div class="box-content report">
                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                                <img class="imageban" src="img/report.png" />
                                                <span><b>Report</b></span>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            <div class="box-right">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="imageban" src="img/img4.jpg"/>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div>
                        <div class="row box">
                            <div class="box-content formal">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/formal_notices.png" />
                                            <span><b>Formal Notices</b></span>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="box-content text">
                                <a href="#">
                                    Open the Formal <br>Notice Document <br>Library
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
            </div>
```

And the CSS is only this line:

```
 .row.box{
     max-width: 345px;
 }
```

I'm stuck in this, any help would be nice. Thanks.

Comment: Read the [docs on how the grid works](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)... *"content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows."*

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the class .box and use the Bootstrap classes instead col-md-4 col-xs-12.